# How many proxies (nginx) layers inside docker is considered too much?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have setup for 1 machine. Currently it looks something like this:

[image]

- Certs - letsecrypt certificates
- static # - static files of react apps
- App - api backend

I don't like this setup for several reasons:

- certs are controlled by certbot and in order to renew them I need to stop my app, launch nginx on host and make update.
- all react apps are in one nginx container, but they logically separated and should be in separate containers. Also build time might be taken in consideration but in multistage build every stage is nicely cached, so it's fine.
- app routing logic coupled with react apps

That's why I come up with another design:

[image]

One nginx instance is on host, it controlled by certbot and redirect all traffic to the docker container.

Each react app is in separate container with own nginx that serve static files.

The only exposed container is "nginx router" and it controls how traffic should be distributed.

I really like this setup, it's nice and modular, but it might have 2 problems:

- potential performance issue because there are too many nginx thingies.
- when using docker it's probably bad practice to have something running on host except for docker.

Answer (score 1):

As you figured, containers should traditionally be single-process. Also avoid mixing host/container contexts, it is really not a maintainable/scalable solution. Containers should be as stateless as possible.

For production, you probably want the top layer (routing) to be some managed load balancing service, which will handle SSL termination for you, is infinitely scalable, and cheap enough (considering setup is easy and no maintenance). In your scenario, unless there is something very very very specific you need where you need to have full manual control of some part, it would be unreasonably painful to setup and maintain.

Static assets should also be hosted behind a CDN if you can (S3 + CloudFront if you like AWS but any other option would work).

For local development, who cares :-) Performance will not be an issue anytime soon.

Also, if you really want to go down that path, you might want to check haproxy, much much more lightweight than nginx if all you want to do is basic routing.